# How to bind a event to keyboard show in cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have searched a lot not find any way to bind a event to my hybrid cordova app on keyboard comes up

I want to do something when keyboard comes up everytime on my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);

function keyboardShowHandler(e){
    console.log('Keyboard height in px: ' + e.keyboardHeight);
}
```

edit - OP also needs to scroll to bottom of app upon keyboard showing

```
function keyboardShowHandler(e){
   document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude can you help me how to scroll to bottom of my app on th keyboard evetn

Comment: sure. while I do that, mark my answer as correct since I answered the asked question.